# Leetcode 383. Ransom Note INCORRECT

Tags: python

This is for Leetcode 383. Ransom Note.

Given two `stings` `ransomNote` and `magazine`, `return true if ransomNote` can be constructed from `magazine` and `false` otherwise.

Each letter in `magazine` can only be used once in `ransomNote`.

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
class Solution(object):
    def canConstruct(self, ransomNote, magazine):
        """
        :type ransomNote: str
        :type magazine: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if len(ransomNote) > len(magazine):
            return False
        
        dict_ransomNote = defaultdict(int)
        dict_magazine = defaultdict(int)
        
        for char in ransomNote:
            dict_ransomNote[char] += 1
        
        for char in magazine:
            dict_magazine[char] += 1
            
        for char in ransomNote:
            if dict_magazine[char] > dict_ransomNote[char]:
                return False
            
        return True
```

Comment: Why is this a class? How are you calling it? Please [edit] to provide a [mre]

Comment: The main problem here is you are getting unexpected output for unknown input, and you're not constructing targeted test cases or using a debugger to probe your program's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

your condition to detect that a letter is missing form the magazine is reversed:

It should be:

```
if dict_magazine[char] < dict_ransomNote[char]:
```

instead of:

```
if dict_magazine[char] > dict_ransomNote[char]:
```

Also, it may be relevant to exclude spaces from the letter check as those are probably not used to form a ransom note from magazine clippings.